# heroku rake db:migrate rake aborted! unable to open database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am currently making my way through the Ruby on Rails tutorial over at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and I am trying to migrate the demo_app database to heroku.

```
heroku rake db:migrate
    rake aborted!
    unable to open database file
```

I have read on other stackoverflow posts that some people fixed this by entering

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do  
  gem "sqlite3-ruby", "~> 1.3.0", :require => "sqlite3"
end
```

in the gemfile. I also entered it into my gemfile and then deleted my old gemfile.lock and redid my bundle install AND rake db:migrate command. I am still receiving the same error.

I am obviously brand new to ruby, rails and heroku but I understand that the problem seems to be that I am using sqlite locally and postgresql in production (on heroku). Do I now have to install this postgresql onto my machine and then RE-migrate the DB? I am afraid I will not be able to get much more out of the tutorials (or ruby on rails itself) if I cannot use heroku.

Comment: Have you tried running: `heroku rake db:migrate --trace` to see if there are any more clues with regards to the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill it!

I was having the same problem and found no solutions. I think something we are doing in those tutorials is leading us to mangle the database.yml file that heroku generates.

I ended up destroying my heroku app

```
heroku destroy
```

and then creating a new one, pushing a fresh copy, and running

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku rakedb:migrate
```

This time everything worked fine! Just make sure you have the pg gem in your gemfile for production

```
group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

and add config/database.yml to your .gitignore file too for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

or if it's working ok locally do a heroku db:push to magically put your local sqlite DB into Heroku's postgresql db.

I always work with the same DB platform locally just so I don't run into any differences (usually only when you start doing DB specific SQL) so I run Postgresql locally too.

Comment: I have searched for sometime and cannot figure out how to use postgre as my native/local sql. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: On a Mac you could you MacPorts or HomeBrew and then install Postgres. Last time I looked Homebrew installed PostGresql9 but if you're just using the shared Heroku Db I think you want to be using Postgres 8.3. http://flux88.com/2010/06/installing-postgresql-for-rails-on-mac-os-x/ is a good place to start.

Comment: I am using windows. I have installed postgres but I think I need to define it in the gemfile and I cannot find how to do that.

Comment: gem 'pg' - but I've got no experience on Windows I'm afraid

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Still not working with heroku but I think I am just going to worry about my local server for now. Frustration setting in too deep! :) Thanks again John.

Comment: Every time you push you will have to do heroku db:push which will destroy all existing data

Comment: Once your initial data is on heroku you want to be doing remote db changes via migrations, not a db:push. But you can push individual tables via --tables <tablename> attribute to heroku db:push

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem... with Heroku interface... ran:
heroku rake db:migrate --trace

and found the problem to be with faker, not being found...Since 'faker' in our Gemfile is loaded in the development group, I loaded it in the production group as well. 
saved Gemfile
bundle install
git add .
git commit -m "fixed faker"
git push
git heroku push
heroku rake db:migrate
heroku rake db:populate

now everything works...the QUESTION, now is what to do with 100 users on my production site?
At least I can continue with Hartl's tutorial!!